# Context's modifies clause violation for class with autocontracts

Tags: dafny

I have a simple class with **autocontracts** in Dafny, that creates a new instance of itself.

But Dafny says that "call might violate context's modifies clause" when I call `foo.Add()` inside `Bar` method

I can't tell why I'm getting this error since the class does not have any attributes

Am I missing something?

```
class {:autocontracts} Foo {

    predicate Valid()

    constructor() { }

    method Add() returns (b:bool)

    method Bar() returns (fo:Foo)
        ensures fresh(fo)
    {
        fo := new Foo();
        var i := 0;
        while(i < 3)
            modifies fo
            invariant fo.Valid()
        {
            var ret := fo.Add(); //call might violate context's modifies clause Verifier
            i := 1 + i;
        }
    }
}
```

Dafny Version at VSCode

```
the installed Dafny version is the latest known: 3.9.0.41003 = 3.9.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have oversimplified your example, because I'm not sure I understand your question.

I think the answer you are looking for is that you should delete the line

```
modifies fo
```

from the loop and add the line

```
invariant fresh(fo.Repr)
```

This fixes the error about violating the context's modifies clause.

The remaining error in the code you did not mention, but it has to do with the autocontracts postcondition for `Bar`, which is

```
this.Valid() && fresh(this.Repr - old(this.Repr))
```

This is doubly confusing because the `Foo` class has no fields, and the `Bar` method never mentions `this`. So one fix would be to make `Bar` a `static` method.

Alternatively, if in your original setting you need `Bar` to be non-static, then you can add the invariant

```
invariant this.Valid() && fresh(this.Repr - old(this.Repr))
```

to the loop to fix this second error.

Comment: Hi James, I think I actually over-simplified my example, but your answer led me to the understanding I was lacking. Thanks